# Twisted server crashes after one day

Tags: python, twisted

I wrote a Udp twisted server and ran it with the following command:

```
nohup python Udpserver2.py &
```

It went well at first, but it brought an error and crashed after 1 day. The error info in `nohup.out` is:

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-15.4.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/python/log.py", line 84, in callWithContext
    return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-15.4.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-15.4.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-15.4.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 597, in _doReadOrWrite
    why = selectable.doRead()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-15.4.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/udp.py", line 248, in doRead
    self.protocol.datagramReceived(data, addr)
  File "UdpServer2.py", line 91, in datagramReceived
    self.device_echo(data, str(host), int(port))
  File "UdpServer2.py", line 19, in device_echo
    cur.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

My python code `UdpServer2.py` is structured like this:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import reactor
import MySQLdb as mdb

conn = mdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='123456', db='kj')

class KjEcho(DatagramProtocol):
    def device_echo(self, msg, host, port):
        device_no = msg[1:7]
        sql = "select did from device where device_no='%s'" % (device_no)

        cur = conn.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cur.execute(sql)                                      #line 19 here

        if 0 == cur.rowcount:
           ...
        else:
           ...
        cur.close()

    def startProtocol(self):
        print 'kj_udp_server starting...'

    def datagramReceived(self, data, (host, port)):
        print "receive msg"
        if(18 != len(data)):
            print 'len err'
            return
        if('0x86' != hex(ord(data[0]))):
            print '0x86 err'
            return
        if(0 == ord(data[15])):
            print 'from device'
            self.device_echo(data, str(host), int(port))      #line 91 here
        else:
            print 'from mobile'
            self.mobile_echo(data, str(host), int(port))

reactor.listenUDP(6000, KjEcho())
reactor.run()
```

Line 91 and line 19 are the reasons indicated above, how to fix it, thanks.

NOTE: There are a lot of machine, Each machine send a message to the server every 20 seconds

Comment: Looks like your database server is unavailable

Comment: The error says your MySQL server has gone away/down...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot relay on mysql connection (or any socket for that matter) remaining alive for unspecified periods of time, especially if there is no data flowing through it. So rather than having one connection that you just reuse to fetch the cursor, close the connection with the cursor and open it again when you need it.

So in essence you want to prefix this line

```
    cur = conn.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```

With one that sets the `conn` and then append the following

```
    cur.close()
```

with one that closes the `conn`, most likely `conn.close()`.

Comment: I am surprised the error doesn't say `connection closed for inactivity` or alike if that's the case, but hey, MySQLdb is not maintained if I recall correctly.

Comment: @Mai that is how it is reported for mysql libs in python AFAIK, i did test few of them with same error thrown. You can read more on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html

Comment: Interesting...this is somewhat misleading...I guess that's just me not having seen this error. Thanks for sharing:)

Comment: @Mai it's not as much an error as result of improper use. You should't be just hanging that idle socket for hours. Rather you should open it for when you need to run queries and close it when you don't.

Comment: There are a lot of machine, Each machine send a message to the server every 20 seconds,   Is it the reason?

Comment: @liuhui it doesn't matter, as eventually it will get shut down if not for that reason then for a broken pipe, which will shut down your application till you manually restart it. What is your reason to keep the lingering socket anyway? It's not like opening sockets is expensive, feel free to time it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, Mai, and Tymoteusz Paul

```
class KjEcho(DatagramProtocol):
    def device_echo(self, msg, host, port):
        device_no = msg[1:7]
        sql = "select did from device where device_no='%s'" % (device_no)

        conn = mdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='123456', db='kj')
        cur = conn.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cur.execute(sql)

        if 0 == cur.rowcount:
           ...
        else:
           ...
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
```

I think it will be fine, However, for the connection, Opened and closed it frequently, Is it better to use connection pool?

Comment: Since you've used my answer, why didn' you just accept it?

Comment: I have accepted your answer, thank for reminding, I am beginner and didn't know how to do.